# How do I resolve: "Unable to cast object of type 'Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection' to type 'Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection'"

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, database-connection, tnsnames

When trying to connect an c#.net application to the database, it gives the following error:

```
Exception:
Unable to cast object of type 'Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection' to type 'Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection'.
Stacktrace:
  at Devart.Data.Oracle.Linq.Provider.OracleDataProvider.Initialize(Object connection)
  at Devart.Data.Linq.DataContext.a(Object A_0, MappingSource A_1, Type A_2)
  at [DatabaseName]Context.[DatabaseName]DataContext..ctor(String connection)
  at [ApplicationName].Form1.DBConnection()
  at [ApplicationName].Form1.btnMutaties_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I am able to ping the database with tns ping, so it is reachable.

I suspect the problem is in the .dll, but I don't know where and how. I could also be in the system settings, because on my local machine it is working, but not on the server.

I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2010
- .NET Framework 3.5
- Devart.Data.Oracle version 6.80.350.0
- Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit

Comment: Did you try doing a clean or rebuild.  Sometimes that will fix this issue.  Otherwise it's likely that you somehow have two different versions of the oracle dll being loaded.

Comment: Can they still be different if they have the same version number and date modified?